# Javascript's JOptionPane equivalent?

Tags: javascript

I've got an alert box but I'd like there to be an `Okay` and then a `Canel` button like a JOptionPane in Java.

Basically it'd work like this...

```
"Message"
 if okay then 
 this();
 else 
 that();
```

Does Javascript have this built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm) function?

```
if (confirm('Message?')) {
  this();
} else {
  that();
}
```

Comment: @downvoter: care to comment? AFAICS, this answer solves the question's problem.